# Add authorization to a specific route without adding attribute in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to add authorization to a particular route without adding Authorize attribute. Is there any way I can do this in startup? I know I can add Authorize attribute globally to all the routes, but I need to add authorize just to a specific method in a controller without touching any code in that controller.

Comment: You can add Authorization to a method by using the [Authorize] tag over the method you wish

Comment: have a better read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: This might be a good time to revisit the requirement of "without touching any code in that controller".  Seems like no matter what you do it's going to be a hack which will make future debugging and support unnecessarily difficult.  Why exactly do you want to change the behavior of something without changing its code?

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to update the controller?

Comment: The route is injected from an external 3rd party dll. I want to secure the url with my authentication mechanism. @Gianlucca I know the one you suggested, but that is not what I need

Comment: if that's the case either you can extend the AuthorizeAttribute, or you can create an HttpModule to handle the request.

Comment: @jomsk1e ok Thanks for the options. But don't we have any other mechanism to do this globally. It is a nice feature to have coz that way we can define the rules in an elegant way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot touch code I see the only solution - check using middleware. Lets imagine that route you want to restrict access is POST '/users/register', so you can use ActionFilter registered globally in startup in which you check url and if its url is '/users/register' you are trying to check token and if token is not valid - return 401.

Also you can use Owin middleware

Here is simple example of implementation such logic using ActionFilter

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new CheckAuthorizationFilterAttribute());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
    public class CheckAuthorizationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var requestUri = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath;
            if (requestUri == "/api/users/register")
            {
                var isTokenValid = ValidateToken();
                if (!isTokenValid)
                    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                return;
            }
        }

        public bool ValidateToken() => false;

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {

        }
    }
```